# memory mangement advanced in c stored variables

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a code example that stores variables in different places of memory: global,dynamic heap,stack and undefined.

I know that all the methods are stored on the stack, all dynamically allocated memory is in the heap and all variables that are not in {} block stored on global area.

I think that variables in a struct get also pointer to dynamic heap in the size of the struct.

So I have some questions about the code

line number (11) where is &(a1) stored?

where is a1 stored?

line number (12) where is a1.arr stored?

line number(21) where is a2->arr stored?

line number(22) &(a2->size) stored?

[That my code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7LK6.png)

```
#define N 4

typedef struct a 
{
    int* arr;
    int size;
}A;
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4};

int main()
{ 
    A a1;
    a1.arr = arr1;
    a1.size = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);     
    A* a2;
    a2 = malloc(sizeof(A));
    int arr2[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N; ++i)
    {
        arr2[i] = i*N;
    }

    a2->arr=arr2;
    a2->size=N;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:

> Line number (12) where is &(a1) stored? where is a1 stored?

a1 is stored on the stack. &(a1) Is an address.

> line number (13) where is a1.arr stored?

Stack, a1.arr specifically is stored in the stack. A pointer is a variable itself that can store another address. If the *value* of the pointer gets changed, the pointer is still kept on the stack, but where it's pointing could be in a different context.

> line number(21) where is a2->arr stored?

a2->arr specifically is stored in the heap. a2 is a pointer to heap memory (hence you called it by malloc), but a2 is still in the stack.

> line number(22) &(a2->size) stored?

Do you mean a2->size? a2->size is stored in the heap.

Comment: can you give me explain why?

Comment: What sort of context are you looking for?

Comment: line number (13) where is a1.arr stored?  i think this stored on global

Comment: @GiladRozmarin you have to be careful about what you mean by a1.arr. A1. arr is a pointer, the pointer is kept on the stack. It points to a global address in the program.

Comment: i am trying to understand if where struct stored and if i have pointer in my struct that point to global area if that effect on the stored

Comment: The stored pointer now points to a global address. The pointer is still on the stack. It sounds like you could  [use a tutorial](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html) of some sort on pointers.